# Losing Data after PHP insert to mysql

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, eventbrite

I'm using the Eventbrite Jquery plugin to get a list of events and post them to a php file using AJAX. I then use PHP to insert the data into mySQL. The problem is, when I search for a 100 events, it gets me all of them back, but only about 80-85 of them show up in the Database.
Could anyone please help me with it?

Here's my PHP code:

```
include_once('dbheader.php');

$event_id = $_POST['ID'];
$title= $_POST['TITLE'];
$category= $_POST['CATEGORY'];
$capacity= $_POST['CAPACITY'];
$date_created = $_POST['DATE_CREATED'];
$end_date = $_POST['END_DATE'];
$status = $_POST['STATUS'];
$event_url = $_POST['EVENT_URL'];
$organizer_name = $_POST['ORGANIZER_NAME'];
$organizer_url = $_POST['ORGANIZER_URL'];
$privacy = $_POST['PRIVACY'];
$repeats = $_POST['REPEATS'];
$venue_address = $_POST['VENUE_ADDRESS'];
$venue_city = $_POST['VENUE_CITY'];
$venue_country = $_POST['VENUE_COUNTRY'];
$venue_id = $_POST['VENUE_ID'];
$venue_postal = $_POST['VENUE_POSTAL'];
$venue_region = $_POST['VENUE_REGION'];
$venue_name = $_POST['VENUE_NAME'];

if(mysql_query("INSERT IGNORE INTO eventbrite (event_id,title,category,capacity,date_created,end_date,status,event_url,organizer_name,organizer_url,privacy,repeats,venue_address,venue_city,venue_country,venue_id,venue_postal_code,venue_region,venue_name)VALUES ('$event_id','$title','$category','$capacity','$date_created','$end_date','$status','$event_url','$organizer_name','$organizer_url','$privacy','$repeats','$venue_address','$venue_city','$venue_country','$venue_id','$venue_postal','$venue_region','$venue_name')")){

echo "Success";
}
else
{echo "Failed";}
```

EDIT:

Using real_escape_string fixed it. This is my first time with mySQL. Thanks a lot to everyone who helped.

P.S: I'll definitely read up on SQL injection and prepared statements

Comment: Probably related to the sql injection problem you have.

Comment: You need to read about [SQL Injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection); you are wide open to it.

Comment: Then your problem is the SELECT, or the INSERT?

Comment: 1) using an obsolete database interface 2) vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com). 3) fixed unchanging error messages, instead of dumping out USEFUL information, like `mysql_error()` output. 4) and since you say you're using ajax, you probably have **NO** error handling on the client side that could catch any error output your script produces, so you're basically just assuming everything will always work perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, consider switching from mysql_query to [PDO prepared statements](http://www.php.net//manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). It's secure and performant for repeated insertions. It has a very intuitive syntax.

Second: try to store all your events in a larger JSON batch to send one big request to the backend and perform a multiple insertion instead of 100 small ones.

At this point, you're probably DOSing your own backend with 100 concurrent requests. Some request get dropped and ajax asynchronous nature silently times them out.

Answer (score 0):

to make this all 1 request create bunch of synchronized arrays from 0 - 99
I think the problem is mysql_real_escape_string and not that. most likely some of these events have ' or something of that nature in them making them unaddable without escape.

from experience doing similar things.
make a string, run mysql_real_escape_string on it then run mysql_query on it

Comment: You were supposed to give me best answer so I gain 15 rep.